# How to change Grey (Buttons-links) on navbar (menu) bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, hyperlink, navbar

i m playing around with bootstrap for the couple past days and it seems that i can't figure out how to change the main color of the links(buttons of the navbar). I am currently using Version 2.3.1 .
I've managed to change the color when on hover(onmouse) to (orange) but i can't change the main color which is something like a light grey. I want it to be black.

![Mouseout] http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/dropdownmouseout.jpg/

![Mouseon] http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/339/dropdownmouseon.jpg/

What i want is where can i find that grey color and if possible the font type and change it. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done some readings from [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons)

...and to achieved your goal, try this out.

```
 <a class="btn btn-inverse"></a>
```